# ExpressJS/NodeJS - Reverse Proxy Deployment

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I have 3 AngularJS application each having their own ExpressJS backend. How do you deploy all 3 applications in this manner:

```
http://myapp.com/<app1>
http://myapp.com/<app2>
http://myapp.com/<app3>
```

**Additional Information:**
- I'm deploying the application in AWS EC2 Instance
- I tried merging the application in a single ExpressJS app. While this works, I still want to know if the case above is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's possible. You'll just need NGINX or Apche running as a reverse proxy for you.

Assuming your node apps are running on local ports 3000, 3001, and 3002, you'd setup a  .conf file with those as upstream servers for the location tags like so:

. . .
    location /app1 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

```
. . .
location /app2 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

}

Read up on more details here:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name es.domain.com;
    location /app1 {
        rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost:3001 https://es.domain.com/appw;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
        auth_basic "Elasticsearch Authentication";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/elasticsearch/user.pwd;
}

    location /app2 {
        rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost:3002 https://es.domain.com/app2;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
        auth_basic "Elasticsearch Authentication";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/elasticsearch/user.pwd;
}
}
```

Please refer this link
http://www.minvolai.com/blog/2014/08/Setting-up-a-Secure-Single-Node-Elasticsearch-server-behind-Nginx/Setting-up-a-Secure-Single-Node-Elasticsearch-server-behind-Nginx/

Answer (score 0):

You can setup [AWS CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) and setup each application as Origins. It provides flexibility to route from single domain(Setup for CloudFront) to different Express Apps and also allows to cache Static content paths at Edge locations.